# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-200]

Tags: spring-boot, h2

Here is the error message.

```
    2020-06-15 13:10:23.623 ERROR 37317 --- [nio-8887-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-200]
### The error may exist in tech/bootcamp/community/mapper/UserMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve tech.bootcamp.community.mapper.UserMapper.insert
### The error occurred while executing an update
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-200]] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-200]
at tech.bootcamp.community.controller.AuthorizeController.callback(AuthorizeController.java:52) ~[classes/:na]

@Autowired
private UserMapper userMapper;
```

> it says this line causes the error.

```
        userMapper.insert(user);
```

So what's the user name and password actually are?

Comment: Connection is usually an application configuration task.

Answer (score 5):

You can set on [`application.properties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database):

```
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
```

If not set explicitly, default values are used, ["sa" and ""](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.java#L65-L66).

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me as well.

```
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Answer (score 1):

After running spring go to http://localhost:8080/h2-console/

Use same config `JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` from your application properties

connect with empty user namer and password if you not set like answer above from DEWA Kazuyuki - 出羽和之.

User Name:
Password:

Answer (score 0):

if we do not want to use default username(sa) and password("") than we need to define username and password in application.properties file example :-

```
spring.datasource.username=mydb
spring.datasource.password=mypass
```

you can use any username and any password if you want to use username other than *sa* , if you are using *sa* as a username then you need to define passwordf as a blank